# Visible portions of windows not redrawn in some applications

Tags: linux, x11, xmonad

Some applications are not updating of their windows, except when the window is made visible again after having been on a hidden virtual workspace.

Clicking on menus results in the opened menu being drawn, but the menus stay visible after they are closed (until window is hidden and unhidden as described above). [edit: This happens on evolution; on evince the menus don't appear at all.]

So far I have seen this happening in Evolution and Evince.

This happens on a machine running Debian Jessie and XMonad.

How should I proceed towards an understanding and elimination of this problem?

**Update**: screenshot of evolution menu confusion

[image: Evolution window not redrawing: closed menus persist]

Comment: I wonder, what happens if you add `import XMonad.Config.Gnome` and use `gnomeConfig` instead of `defaultConfig`. I believe you need `libghc-xmonad-dev` and [libghc-gconf-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stable/haskell/libghc-gconf-dev) to achieve that.  If it works in that scenario it means that evolution/evince are too dependent on `gconf`

Comment: @grochmal I am already using `gnomeConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

`xmonad` is non-reparenting and this causes issues with some applications.  Moreover, the problem happens because the applications do not know that `xmonad` is a non-reparenting window manager.

A common solution to this is to set `xmonad`'s window manager name to *LG3D*. `lg3d` is an ancient window manager written in `java`, but, since it has been a huge hype when its development started, several libraries are aware of it (and not aware of `xmonad`).

To set `xmonad`'s WM name as *LG3D* you need to add a hook to your `monad.hs`:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName

main = do
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { startupHook = setWMName "LG3D" }
```

References:

- [xmonad FAQ](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be neither the problem (exactly the same XMonad config works fine on other machines) nor the solution (I already have `startupHook = setWMName "LG3D"` in my config).

Comment: @jacg - i'm baffled, i run `xmonad` (one of my machines do run it on Debian Jessie) and absolutely cannot replicate anything strange in `evince`.  Maybe if you give us a screenshot someone will be able to replicate it.

Comment: Added screenshot. I'm baffled too: I'm running what were initially identical installs on 3 machines with identical hardware, and I can't reproduce it on the others. The only thing I can think of is that the problem machine is the only one onto which (after some time) I installed a session manager. What irks me is that I have no clue how to debug this. Where does one start?